# Incremental backup with rollforward logs: How to get the logs with MySQL commands?

Tags: mysql, logging, logfile

I have a MySQL database with activated binary logging (i.e. rollforward logs). The logs are located (by default) in `/var/log/mysql` which is accessible by the users `mysql` and `root` only.

I make (full) backups every Sunday with a cronjob like this:

```
mysqldump -u root --flush-logs $database > $database.sql
mysql -u root -e 'purge binary logs before now();'
            # or "reset master", which is the same
```

I know that `mysqldump` has no option for *incremental* backups and the binary logs actually *are* the incremental backup -- or at least can bee seen as such.
So every Wednesday I make an incremental backup by flushing and copying the binlog files:

```
mysql -u root -e 'flush binary logs;'
cp /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.* $some_backup_path
```

(Code to sort out the current binlog omitted here.)

There are various commands to inspect the binlog files, like

```
show binary logs;                    -- display
flush binary logs;                   -- start a new one
reset master;                        -- delete all and start over
purge binary logs before $some_date; -- delete older logs
```

However, there seems to be no MySQL command to *fetch* them. **The only way seems to copy them with "regular" Unix commands, like `cp` or `rsync` as user `root`. Is that true?**

I know there are other ways to make backups, such as the MySQL Enterprise stuff or simply backing up the `/var/lib/mysql` directory. I'm just curious.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by fetching logs?

Comment: Note that for some table types copying `/var/lib/mysql` doesn't work v well. You'll miss anything in memory that hasn't been committed.

Comment: @Shadow Copying them to the local filesystem into a directory of my choice. Like `mysqldump` fetches the DDL and the full data to a file of my choice.

Comment: Yes, it's true. There are myriad OS commands to copy files over a network but none specifically written for MySQL. MySQLDump merely provides the Host/User/PW like the std mysql client.

Comment: @ethrbunny Good point. But it would be OK for me (and my users) if I'd shutdown the whole DB for a couple of minutes within a maintenance window. Actually my full backup is so fast (< 3 secs.) that I don't really _need_ incremental backups at all. I'm doing them for fun and learning so I know when times come.

Comment: I stand corrected. @shadow FTW!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mysqlbinlog utility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html) to administer binary log files, including copying them to another location. Within mysql you can use [show binlog events command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-binlog-events.html) to access most of the contents within a binary log.

Comment: Ahh, I wasn't aware of the `show binlog events`. Thank you. I know `mysqlbinlog` as it is crucial for applying the binlog. It works fine but only with local files I thought. But when you pointed me to the docs I noticed the [--read-from-remote-server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_read-from-remote-server) option. I think that's exactly what I was looking for. The binary logs in their binary form are of no use anyway.